# How do i pass two different string value when button is pressed and released?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using one button for "on" and "off" in asp.net c#. When i click that button it is "on" and when i click that same button second time it is "off". Now i want to do this within one click. This means that once i click  on button it should pass string Value="1" and it will be on, when released that button it should pass string value="2" and it will be off. Please let me know how can i do that !

```
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SerialPort ardo;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ardo = new SerialPort();
            ardo.PortName = "COM5";
            ardo.BaudRate = 9600;
        }
        protected void BlueOn(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(Session["currentState"] == null)
               Session["currentState"] = "2";

           if(Session["currentState"].ToString() == "1")
             {

                Session["currentState"]= "2";
             }
             else
             {

                Session["currentState"]= "1"; 
             }
            ardo.Open();
            ardo.Write(Session["currentState"].ToString());
            ardo.Close();

            //string blue = "a";
            //ardo.Open();
            //ardo.Write(blue);
            //ardo.Close();
        }
```

Comment: `Session["currentState"] = (Session["currentState"] == "1") ? "2" : "1"`

Comment: How can i use this code? Because there will be one click on button. Should i use any jquery ajax method for that ?

Comment: I don't think server control buttons can work like that; there's no 'onkeydown' 'onkeyup' events like html buttons, there's just one event per click.

Comment: But , we can call two functions in script for button.

Comment: Yes, keyup, keydown. So you could call code-behind from javascript. Research `Page Methods`. Note - you cannot change anything on the page using Page Methods, but you can call code-behind and return values back to the javascript methods, then change the page there, if you need to.

Comment: Can you please help me on that , how can i call code-behind from javascript ?

Comment: Research Page Methods. It can't be explained simply in comments.

Comment: P.s., page methods are considered part of `ASP.NET AJAX`. (`asp.net-ajax` tag on SO.)

Comment: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2007/08/28/creating-and-consuming-aspnet-ajax-page-methods.aspx

Comment: I understand that, they give example in VB, but i'm confused as i'm very new in this field. How the code should be to rectify my requirement in this issue, can you please give example code for this ?

Comment: Pls try like this, 
Initially set Button text as 'ON'
and in it's click event
     protected void Button1_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
       {
          if (Button1.Text.Equals("ON"))
          {
                fun_process(1);
                Button1.Text= "OFF";
          }
        else
         {
             fun_process(2);
                Button1.Text= "ON";
        }
    }